# how to use {{$variable}} in css , Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, css, forms, laravel-5

I know we can use {{$variable}} in html for php variables but can I do the same in css. Is it even possible or I am doing something wrong here ?

```
<form style="color:{{$values['color']}};" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
```

Comment: What is in `$variable`?

Comment: color value , but main thing is I can use `{{$values['color']}}` to output color value but it does not work in css, I am here being specific to the use of {{}} , double curly braces. I know other methods like `<?php echo $values['color']?>`  @b0s3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you varaible is valid and holds something like `"#f90"`, then you can do:

```
style="color:<?= $values['color']; ?>;"
```

or

```
style="color:<?php echo $values['color']; ?>;"
```

if you view/template is a .php then this will work (even if using laravel, you can still use plain php in your views).
Are you using any templating other then the default blade template? if not using  `{{{` should also work.

```
style="color:{{{ $values['color'] }}}"
```

n.b again these will only work if you varaible is holding the correct data. if you are still having issues try a `die(var_dump($values));` to check the values are as you'd expect